# Ethernet internet not completely working

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

I have tried setting up a manual IP.

`/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
address X
netmask X
gateway X
dns-nameservers X X
```

`ping` does not work with my gateway.

`ping` does work with 8.8.8.8 (I don't understand why).

I can ping this server from other computers on the network, but not from others on different networks.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With all respect, your internal IP addresses are probably not routable, and certainly not if you set up your network properly. Therefore, they are not reachable over the Internet, and hiding them is unnecessarily paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have a hidden error (surely you don't have `address X` in your file), and using `X` for all values makes it hard for me to tell you to do:

```
ip route
sudo ip route add X dev enp0s31f6
```

In this case, by `X`, I mean the same `X` you hid from us in

```
gateway X
```